# Why is the database of the webapp in the book "Head First Python 2nd Edition" not working as it should?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, flask, mysql-python

I'm currently studying Python by reading the book "Head First Python 2nd Edition" and it is really helpful and well-written, but I think it is a little anachronistic (since it was released on December 16, 2016, I think that various things changed since then).

The problem is: I have just finished writing (for what I had to do so far) the webapp *vsearch4web.py*, and it looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, escape
from vsearch import search4letters

from DBcm import UseDatabase

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['dbconfig'] = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
                          'user': 'vsearch',
                          'password': 'vsearchpasswd',
                          'database': 'vsearchlogDB', }


def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: str) -> None:
    """Log details of the web request and the results"""

    with UseDatabase(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
        _SQL = """insert into log
              (phrase, letters, ip, browser_string, results) 
              values
              (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        cursor.execute(_SQL, (req.form['phrase'],
                              req.form['letters'],
                              req.remote_addr,
                              req.user_agent.browser,
                              res, ))
    
@app.route('/search4', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> 'html':
    phrase = request.form['phrase']
    letters = request.form['letters']
    title = 'Here are your results:'
    results = ''.join(search4letters(phrase, letters))
    log_request(request, results)
    return render_template('results.html',
                           the_title=title,
                           the_phrase=phrase,
                           the_letters=letters,
                           the_results=results,)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Welcome to search4letters on the web!')


@app.route('/viewlog')
def view_the_log() -> 'html':
    with UseDatabase(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
        _SQL = """Select phrase, letters, ip, browser_string, results
                  from log"""
        cursor.execute(_SQL)
        contents = cursor.fetchall()
    titles = ('Phrase', 'Letters', 'Remote_addr', 'User_agent', 'Results')
    return render_template('viewlog.html',
                           the_title='View Log',
                           the_row_titles=titles,
                           the_data=contents,)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the class I used in the code:

```
import mysql.connector

class UseDatabase:

    def __init__(self, config: dict) -> None:
        self.configuration = config

    def __enter__(self) -> 'cursor':
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(**self.configuration)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace) -> None:
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()
```

Then I created the database **"vsearchlogDB"** in the MySQL console, and afterwards (logged in as the user **"vsearch"**), I created the table **"log"** (typing exactly what was written on the book, even if the resulting table is slightly different, this is why I said before that this book may be a little anachronistic):

[image: table log]

(This is the table that is shown in the book):

[image: table log of the book]

Now when I run my webapp locally and try it out, this error comes out:

mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1048 (23000): Column 'browser_string' cannot be null

Someone can please explain why the code is not able to extract the value of the browser_string?

I tried to re-create the table from scratch and to put the browser_string column null, and in fact in the column of browser_string (in the /viewlog page) it always displays *None* (even though I think that this is a useless test, that because I do not know how to use MySQL), but it should not be like this, can someone explain?

Here I also add the HTML and CSS codes of (all) of the pages of the webapp (sorry for all the code, but I really can't figure out where the problem is):

base.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
    
        <title>{{ the_title }}</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/hf.css" />
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        {% block body %}
        

        {% endblock %}
    </body>
    
</html>
```

entry.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<h2>{{ the_title }}</h2>

<form method='POST' action='/search4'>
<table>
<p>Use this form to submit a search request:</p>
<tr><td>Phrase:</td><td><input name='phrase' type='TEXT' width='60'></td></tr>
<tr><td>Letters:</td><td><input name='letters' type='TEXT' value='aeiou'></td></tr>
</table>
<p>When you're ready, click this button:</p>
<p><input value="Do it!" type="submit"></p>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

results.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<h2>{{ the_title }}</h2>

<p>You submitted the following data:</p>
<table>
<tr><td>Phrase:</td><td>{{ the_phrase }}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Letters:</td><td>{{ the_letters }}</td></tr>
</table>

<p>When "{{ the_phrase }}" is searched for "{{ the_letters }}", the following 
results are returned:</p>
<h3>{{ the_results }}</h3>

{% endblock %}
```

viewlog.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<h2>{{ the_title }}</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        {% for row_title in the_row_titles %}
            <th>{{row_title}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for log_row in the_data %}
        <tr>
            {% for item in log_row %}
                <td>{{item}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

hf.css:

```
body {
    font-family:      Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:        medium;
    background-color: tan;
    margin-top:       5%;
    margin-bottom:    5%;
    margin-left:      10%;
    margin-right:     10%;
    border:           1px dotted gray;
    padding:          10px 10px 10px 10px;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration:  none; 
    font-weight:      600; 
  }
  a:hover {
    text-decoration:  underline;
  }
  a img {
    border:           0;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size:        150%;
  }
  table {
    margin-left:      20px;
    margin-right:     20px;
    caption-side:     bottom;
    border-collapse:  collapse;
  }
  td, th {
    padding:          5px;
    text-align:       left;
  }
  .copyright {
    font-size:        75%;
    font-style:       italic;
  }
  .slogan {
    font-size:        75%;
    font-style:       italic;
  }
  .confirmentry {
    font-weight:      600; 
  }
  
  /*** Tables ***/
  
  table {
  font-size:          1em;
  background-color:   #fafcff;
  border:             1px solid #909090;
  color:              #2a2a2a;
  padding:            5px 5px 2px;
  border-collapse:    collapse;
  }
  
  td, th {
  border:             thin dotted gray;
  }
  
  /*** Inputs ***/
  input[type=text] {
    font-size:        115%;
    width:            30em;
  }
  input[type=submit] {
    font-size:        125%;
  }
  select {
    font-size:        125%;
  }
```

Comment: It looks correct to me. It's attempting to get the browser from the flask request's user_agent, which is the right place to look. You could do something like `req.user_agent.browser if req.user_agent.browser is not None else 'Unknown'` or some such trickery to ensure a value is passed into the INSERT statement. Or you could modify the table to allow NULL values in that column so you can get through your tutorial.

Comment: Yeah, I could do something like that, but still I can't figure out why the program does not take the value of the name of the browser (I tried different browser, but the result was the same), and it is strange, because when I previously printed the value (of the whole req.user_agent not req.user_agent.browser) in a .txt file it was all ok, then I tried to change (on the current program that you see on this site) from req.user_agent.browser to req.user_agent, but then MySQL displayed this message error: _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type UserAgent cannot be converted, so Idk

Comment: (I write another comment for characters limitation) So, do you think this might be a database problem (since it is slightly different, even if the record of the field browser_string are the same) or something else?

Comment: When you print out `req.user_agent` does it show an object that has `browser` as one of the keys? I'm really not sure why it would fail. Your python is correct. The problem isn't a database problem. It's just an overall issue where the current code + table isn't built in such a way to allow things like a `None` browser. The code is correct. The table is correct. It's just not super hardened since it doesn't anticipate and handle edge cases like this gracefully.

Comment: When I print out 'req.user_agent' (in the .txt file) it shows (it is an example here): Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9

Comment: It shows all the information, but when it comes to only the name, there is a problem (In addition to the problem, as I said before, of the _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type UserAgent cannot be converted)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this description：https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-python
The following code can successfully obtain browser information, I have tested it successfully, you can try it：

```
from ua_parser import user_agent_parser    #Note the code here

web_detial = str(request.user_agent)    #Note the code here
user_browser = user_agent_parser.ParseUserAgent(web_detial)    #Note the code here
browser = user_browser['family']    #Note the code here

---
cursor.execute(_SQL, (req.form['phrase'],
                      req.form['letters'],
                      req.remote_addr,
                      browser,    #Note the code here
                      res, ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser data is not transferred.

Solution:
Change the line `req.user_agent.browser` to `req.headers.get('User-Agent')`

Answer (score 0):

About your issue of the browser returning *None* even after putting in your `phrase` which I know prevents you from getting the results (because I am following the same book) is probably emanating from the `vsearch.py` file. Did you ensure you use `return` statement in the `def search4vowels` and `def search4letters` functions?

Also make sure the `vsearch.py` was properly saved as a sdist file

Answer (score 0):

I did as AntipovIV suggested, change req.user_agent.browser to req.headers.get('User-Agent')

Then I ran

```
mysql> alter table log MODIFY COLUMN browser_string varchar(255);
```

[Browser is long and ugly, but at least it still gets logged! Nulls are from before I changed req.user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNVxn.png)